# 500 (Internal Server error) and Typeerror

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm running into an error when trying to send an email.

First, i get a status code POST http://localhost:3000/api/email 500 internal server error when testing on my webpage.

Second, my server is giving me a TypeError: cannot read property 'email' of undefined.

Below i pasted my server code giving me an error and my contactpage code where im using axios to post. Would greatly appreciate all help!

```
class ContactPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            message: '',
            disabled: false,
            emailSent: null,
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            disabled: true,
        });

        Axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/email', this.state)
            .then(res => {
                if(res.data.success) {
                    this.setState ({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: true
                    });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: false
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                
                this.setState({
                    disabled: false,
                    emailSent: false
                });
            })
    }
```

```
app.post('/api/email', (res, req, next) => {

    sendGrid.setApiKey(SG_API_KEY);
    const msg = {
        to: PE,
        from: req.body.email,
        subject: 'Website Contact',
        text: req.body.message
    }

    sendGrid.send(msg)
        .then(result => {

            res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            
            console.log('error: ', err);
            res.status(401).json({
                success: false
            });

        });

});
```

Comment: what is it showing when you console.log() your state on the onSubmit method ?

Comment: You have your `req` and `res` parameters the wrong way around. It should be `app.post('/api/email', (req, res, next)`

Comment: @lawrence-witt That fixed it! thank you!! can't believe it was a simple error....